# How to get polyline coordinates in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, line

Using leafletjs, I created a polyline connecting a bunch of markers:

```
var line = L.polyline( latlngs, {
  weight: 5,
  color: '#8EE9FF'
})
```

Now, I am trying to get the start and end markers when I click on a polyline:

```
line.on('click',(e)=>{
  // get starting marker
  // get ending marker
})
```

Looking at `e`, I see the entire list of latlgns but I just need 2 for the line segment I clicked on. Is it not possible? Should I create multiple separate lines instead?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE! Could you provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) (or similar) so that others can test your map?

Comment: Actually, we require that the relevant code snippet be placed in the body of the question. Fiddles are all well and good, but if it's external to Stack Exchange, it's ephemeral, and therefore likely to damage the question when it disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code uses [Leaflet.GeometryUtil](https://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/) to check whether the clicked `LatLng` is on a segment and then populates `start` and `end` variables with the respective `LatLng`s of that segment.

```
line.on("click", (e) => {
  let i = 0,
    start = {},
    end = {}
  const verts = e.target.getLatLngs() // verts...vertices of polyline

  //Loop through vertices while there is one at index i + 1
  while (verts[i + 1]) {
    //belongsSegment returns a Boolean
    const segmentFound = L.GeometryUtil.belongsSegment(e.latlng, verts[i], verts[i+1])
    if (segmentFound) {
      start = verts[i]
      end = verts[i + 1]
      break
    }
    i++
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I ended up using multiple lines already and that works but your answer looks correct.

Comment: Interesting - It messes up when having multiple parallel lines in different length